# Radio button array get selected value AND related content (same id hidden elements)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm having problems with extracting the data from a radio button form.

**It looks like this:**

```php
<?php
## color
$stripe = 1;
$att_color=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE products_id ='".$row['products_id']."' AND att_head='colors' AND att_show='1' ORDER BY att_order asc");
if(mysql_num_rows($att_color)!=0)
{
echo "
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width=\"90%\" align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#EDEDED\">Color</td>
<td width=\"10%\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#891531\">
<a href=\"#2\" title=\"Yta / Behandling\"><img src=\"images/info.png\"></a>
</td>
</tr>";

while($color_row=mysql_fetch_array($att_color)){
  if ($color_row['att_standard'] == 1) { $standard = "checked"; }
echo "
<tr class=".(($stripe++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even').">
  <td colspan=\"2\" width=\"100%\">
<input name=\"color_name[]\" value=\"".$color_row['att_name']."\" id=\"".$color_row['att_order']."\" type=\"hidden\" />
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"color_selected[]\" id=\"".$color_row['att_order']."\" value=\"".(round($color_row['att_val']*0.85))."\" ".$standard.">
<img src=\"images/colors/".$colorimg."\"> &nbsp;".$color_row['att_name']."</td>
 </tr>";
unset($standard); }
echo "</table>"; }
# END color
?>
```

Only ONE option is to be allowed. 
When someone hits submit I* need to get the value AND the corresponding name from that row.
However I can't seem to figure the foreach syntax out.

```php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {   
    $c_selected = $_POST['color_selected'];
    $c_name = $_POST['color_name'];
    foreach($c_selected as $key => $n) {
    echo "<br><br>". $c_selected[$key] ." ".$c_name[$key];
 }
```

The current code gives me the correct value, but the wrong colorname. (always 1st option)
How can I get this to work?

Comment: just side note: please improve style for your code

Comment: Your foreach loop should look like:

`foreach ($c_selected as $key => $n) { print("<br /><br />" . $n . " " . $c_name[$key]); }`, for a start.

Answer (score 0):

This is broke:

```
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"color_selected[]\" id=\"".$color_row['att_order']."\" value=\"".(round($color_row['att_val']*0.85))."\" ".$standard.">

 name=\"color_selected[]\" should not be an array.
```

Instead just

```
 name=\"color_selected\" will provide the chosen color.
```

So the value of the radio button should be the color, not the cost of the item.
You should make another hidden field with the value of the item, unless each color is a different price.

I think the problem is more complicated because you are trying to send an order array rather than a simple form or something. If this is the case, maybe you have to rethink the way you are doing this.

You seem to have a products id field, it should be unique for each color and can be used on the other side to get all the data values from your database.

```
<input name=\"att_order\"
       value=\"".$color_row['att_order']."\" 
       type=\"hidden\" />
<input type=\"radio\" 
       name=\"color_selected\" 
       value=\"".$color_row['products_id']."\" 
       ".$standard.">
```

Comment: The prices are unique and i need to get the name from the same row in the db, so if i choose red value is 1740 and name is "red" i need the result to be red: 1740.

Comment: i thought that making color_selected[] an array, and then sort the whole output could make me exclude from the array where not all attributes are set (since color_selected is the only unique)

Comment: since they have the same order_id